# Returning a value with node inquirer package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm attempting to use the node.js inquirer package to run a simple flashcard generator. I'm having trouble getting the syntax to return the checkbox the user clicked. So, once the user makes a choice, I'd like to be able to log the result of that choice. Currently this console.log() returns "undefined".

Any help appreciated!

```
inquirer.prompt ([
{
type: "checkbox",
name: "typeOfCard",
message: "Select an action.",
choices: [
  {
    name: "Create a Basic Card"
  },
  {
    name: "Create a Cloze Card"
  },
  {
    name: "Run the flashcards!"
  }
 ]
  }
   ]).then(function(answers){
 console.log(answers.typeOfCard[0])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

inquirer.prompt ([
{
type: "checkbox",
name: "typeOfCard",
message: "Select an action.",
choices: [
  "Create a Basic Card",
  "Create a Cloze Card",
  "Run the flashcards!"
 ]
  }
   ]).then(function(answers){
 console.log(answers.typeOfCard);
});
```

`choices` should just be an array of strings.  You will then be returned an array containing the selected items, ex:

```
[ 'Create a Cloze Card', 'Run the flashcards!' ]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inquirer = require("inquirer");

console.clear();

const main = async() => {

    const readCardChoise = () => {
        const read = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            inquirer.prompt ([
                {
                type: "checkbox",
                name: "typeOfCard",
                message: "Select an action.",
                choices: [
                      {
                        name: "Create a Basic Card"
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Create a Cloze Card"
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Run the flashcards!"
                      }

                 ],
                validate(answer) {
                if (answer.length < 1) {
                    return 'You must choose at least one card.';
                }
                return true;
                },
                  }])
                   .then((answers) => {
                    resolve(answers.typeOfCard);
                });
        });

        return read;

    }

    const cadSelect = await readCardChoise();
    console.log(cadSelect)

}

main();
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should always add an explanation of the answer, not just code  that supposedly works